# ajax call doesn't get any response

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

i have three dropdown lists on wordpress plugin the second one values is depending on the chosen value of the first dropdown so i used ajax to send the request but am not getting any response
here is my code i found it on a sit and trying to use it

index.php

```
  <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:index
 * 
 * Version: 1.0
 *
 */


 function try_form()
    {



 include "connect_db.php"; ?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>
       <!-- Country dropdown -->
       <select id='sel_country' >
          <option value='0' >Select Country</option>
          <?php 
          ## Fetch countries
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cities ");
          $stmt->execute();
          $countriesList = $stmt->fetchAll();

          foreach($countriesList as $country){
             echo "<option value='".$country['ID']."'>".$country['city_name']."</option>";
          }
          ?>
       </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>State</td>
    <td>
      <select id='sel_state' >
         <option value='0' >Select State</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>
      <select id='sel_city' >
        <option value='0' >Select City</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </table>
   <script type="text/javascript">    
  
  
  
  
  
  $(document).ready(function(){

  // Country
  $('#sel_country').change(function(){

     var countryid = $(this).val();

     // Empty state and city dropdown
     $('#sel_state').find('option').not(':first').remove();
     $('#sel_city').find('option').not(':first').remove();

     // AJAX request
     $.ajax({
       url: "ajaxfile.php",
       type: 'post',
       data: {request: 1, countryid:countryid},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){
alert (countryid);
         var len = response.length;

         for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
           var ID = response[i]['ID'];
           var name = response[i]['name'];

           $("#sel_state").append("<option value='"+ID+"'>"+name+"</option>");

         }
       },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');}
     });

  });

  // State
  $('#sel_state').change(function(){
     var stateid = $(this).val();

     // Empty city dropdown
     $('#sel_city').find('option').not(':first').remove();

     // AJAX request
     $.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxfile.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: {request: 2, stateid: stateid},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){

         var len = response.length;

         for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
           var id = response[i]['id'];
           var name = response[i]['name'];

           $("#sel_city").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");

         }
       }
     });
   });
});
  </script>
<?php  } add_shortcode('t', 'try_form');
```

ajaxfile.php    file

```
<?php

include "connect_db.php";

$request = 0;

if(isset($_POST['request'])){
   $request = $_POST['request'];
}

// Fetch state list by countryid
if($request == 1){
   $countryid = $_POST['countryid'];

   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM m where mm= :country");
  // $stmt->bindValue(':country', (int)$countryid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

   $stmt->execute();
   $statesList = $stmt->fetchAll();

   $response = array();
   foreach($statesList as $state){
      $response[] = array(
        "ID" => $state['ID'],
        "name" => $state['name']
      );
   }

   echo json_encode($response);
   exit;
}

// Fetch city list by stateid
if($request == 2){
   $stateid = $_POST['stateid'];

   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state=:state ORDER BY name");
   $stmt->bindValue(':state', (int)$stateid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

   $stmt->execute();
   $statesList = $stmt->fetchAll();

   $response = array();
   foreach($statesList as $state){
      $response[] = array(
         "id" => $state['id'],
         "name" => $state['name']
      );
   }

   echo json_encode($response);
   exit;
}
```

so any idea why i am not getting any response

edit
i have seen the network tab of my browser's developer toolbar and i get this

[  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y59jC.png
]
and i edited the bindValue to bindParam and now i am getting failur

Comment: if you are not getting anthing that means the code is not entering to any if block.
that means either you are not passing 'request' value correctly or you are not parsing it correclty in php side.

Comment: in that case shouldn't it at least showing the alert i have put in the success or error?? @newbie

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser's developer toolbar to see if the AJAX requests are being triggered at all.

Comment: And I can see you've tried to use parametrized queries. This is the right way to go, you just used the wrong method, it's supposed to be `bindParam`, not `bindValue`.

Comment: @anna
no. 
since you are not getting anything from server side success will not be called on js side.
try to put default result in server side and see whether you are getting it.

Comment: i have edited my question @El_Vanja  @ newbie

Comment: 404 means "Not Found", which means your AJAX `url` parameter is incorrect. Where is `ajaxfile.php` in the folder structure compared to the one that uses AJAX?

Comment: i know but don't understand why it is giving me that ,i have both files in the same folder with the connect_db file @ El_Vanja

Comment: @ El_Vanja thanks really you showed me exactly where the problem were i just updated the ajax url with my domain name

Comment: `$stmt->bindParam(':country', $countryid, PDO::PARAM_INT);` you dont need `(int)`

Comment: thanks for your answer the problem was with the ajax Url i had to add my domain name @ Dlk